# How to place a char on a 2d array for 8 queens program in C

Tags: c, arrays, 2d

I'm trying to develop a solution to the [8 queens puzzle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle), where 8 queens should be placed on an 8x8 chess board so that no two can attack each other.  I am able to print out my board of '#' but can't figure out how to place a queen in the first spot and make all horizontal, vertical, and diagonal spots an 'x'.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#define ROW 8
#define COL 8

// Make the chessboard

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    char board[ROW][COL];
    int i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < COL; j++)
        {
            board[i][j] = '#';
            printf(" %c", board[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

// Place queen on first '#'

int placeQueen(char board[ROW][COL])
{
    char queenSpace;
    int i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < COL; j++)
        {
            queenSpace = 'Q';
            board[i][j] = queenSpace;
            printf(" %c", board[1][1]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output right now is on the left, I need it to be as shown on the right:

```
# # # # # # # #            Q x x x x x x x
# # # # # # # #            x x # # # # # #
# # # # # # # #            x # x # # # # #
# # # # # # # #            x # # x # # # #
# # # # # # # #            x # # # x # # #
# # # # # # # #            x # # # # x # #
# # # # # # # #            x # # # # # x #
# # # # # # # #            x # # # # # # x
```

Here is my algorithm:

1. Create an 8x8 array with all '#'.
2. Place a queen on first available '#'.
3. Change all horizontal, vertical, and diagonal squares from queen position to 'x'.
4. Place another queen on first spot that is a '#'.
5. Change all horizontal, vertical, and diagonal squares from new queen position to 'x'.
6. Repeat steps 4-5 till no more '#' available.
7. If > 7 queens, print array and run again.
8. If <= 7 queens, run again but with '#' marked at 2nd queen's location and repeat steps 4-5.
9. if > 7 queens, print array and run again.
10. if <= 7 queens, repeat step 8 till no more '#' in 2nd queen's row.
11. if no more '#' in 2nd queen's row, free memory from that row.
12. Repeat step 8 but for 3rd queen's position.
13. Repeat steps 8 - 11 but for 4th queen's position. Etc.
14. If no more solutions, repeat steps 2-13 but mark '#' where 1st queen was this time.
15. Repeat step 14 till no more '#' in first row.

I have never done any work or programs using 2d arrays so any help or even sample code would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: For starters you never call `placeQueen`. You're also looping over your whole board when you claim you just need it in one space.

Comment: What are the indices of the squares on some square's row? What are the indices of the squares on some square's column? Somewhat harder question: What are the indices of the squares on some square's diagonals? Once you have figured that out you can put x's on those squares. Also, you need to learn about backtracking. Search SO for that, or just for eight queens ... it's a common problem and has been discussed before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some hints. Abstract your main data type:

```
#define ROW 8
#define COL 8
typedef char t_board[ROW][COL];
#define ItRows(Var) for (int Var = 0; Var < ROW; Var++)
#define ItCols(Var) for (int Var = 0; Var < COL; Var++)
#define EMPTY  '+'
#define QUEEN  'Q'
#define ATTACK '-'

#define bool int
#define true 1
#define false 0
```

then you can simplify the declaration of operations to be done on the datatype and concentrate on logic of the single steps:

```
void init(t_board board) {
   ItRows(r)
       ItCols(c)
           board[r][c] = EMPTY;
}
void show(t_board board) {
   ItRows(r) {
       ItCols(c)
           printf(" %c", board[r][c]);
       printf("\n");
   }
}
void assign(t_board target, const t_board source) {
   ItRows(r)
       ItCols(c)
           target[r][c] = source[r][c];
}
bool reserve(t_board board, int row, int col, char cell) {
    if (board[row][col] == QUEEN)
        return false;
    board[row][col] = cell;
    return true;
}
bool place_queen(t_board board, int row, int col) {
   ItRows(r)
       if (r != row && !reserve(board, r, col, ATTACK))
           return false;
    ItCols(c)
       if (c != col && !reserve(board, row, c, ATTACK))
           return false;

    #define AttackDiag(R, C) \
       for (int r = row + R, c = col + C; r >= 0 && c >= 0 && r < ROW && c < COL; r += R, c += C) \
          if (!reserve(board, r, c, ATTACK)) \
              return false;
    AttackDiag(+1, +1)
    AttackDiag(+1, -1)
    AttackDiag(-1, +1)
    AttackDiag(-1, -1)

    return reserve(board, row, col, QUEEN);
}
int main_queens(int argc, char **argv) {
    t_board b;
    init(b);
    assert(place_queen(b, 3, 2));
    show(b);
    return 0;
}
```